# Get Answer from server using a Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, handler

I am using a Handler for run server code, from the browser i can see the answer from the server, but i can not get it in my source.

I am calling the handler like that:

```
           $.ajax({
            type : "json",
            url : "../Handlers/Handler.ashx?MethodName=ReadAnswerServerID",
            success : function(data){
                alert('inside success');
            }
        });
```

I can get the answer inside the success block, but i never can´t see the alert for example.

This is the handler:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string method = context.Request.QueryString["MethodName"].ToString();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        switch (method)
        {
            case "ReadAnswerServerID":
                context.Response.Write(ReadID());
                break;
        }
    }
```

ReadID return a string value.

Comment: `I can get the answer inside the success block, but i never can´t see the alert` If you don't see tha alert, then success code is not execeuted. Use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and compare what your code and browser send...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "ReadID()" returns valid JSON, if not that might be your problem.

You can set a breakpoint inside ProcessRequest, attach to w3wp and hit the breakpoint when your Javascript call executes ?

If not, have you checked your handler registration in web.config ?

Comment: thanks! it was the key! i was returning a normal stirng, using this: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(); i arrive to the success block, thanks for the help!!